# Looking for a custom ROM for HTC Inspire 4G

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, custom-roms, htc-sense, htc-desire-hd, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

The ROM should have:

- Android 4.0+
- WiFi hotspot
- 4G capability
- Long battery life
- Increased volume
- Fast speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you looked around yourself before asking, but here are a few I found:

1. CM10.1 unofficial

   This ROM has JellyBean and works for Inspire 4G and the HTC Ace. [XDA link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073997%22Heres%20the%20XDA%20link%22).
2. MIUI.us v2.10

   A popular, heavily styled ROM running JellyBean. It also comes with an app called toolbox which allows you to customize the ROM. Eg, overclock option. [XDA link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1589306).